# How to connect to raspberry Pi over internet if we know only its MAC Address

Tags: http, socket.io, ionic-framework, raspberry-pi

I have Raspberry Pi and a mobile app developed in ionic.It has to communicate over SocketIO and normal HTTP request. I can communicate if i know IP address and port no. But what if I'm using it over internet and my raspberry pi's IP address is changing dynamically due to DHCP. How do i connect to my raspberry Pi device. Is their a way to connect if I know MAC address of Rasspberry PI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short Answer: `no`

Slightly Longer:

MAC is only useful at Layer 2. So the minute you have a router between you and the device, you will no longer be able to see the MAC. If you control the Layer 2 network you can statically assign a DHCP address, or you can look at the logs and see what IP it was assigned,  but if the device is connecting to networks you don't control and its address is changing, you will need a way for the Raspberry Pi to register where it currently lives.  There are a variety of ways to do this,  such as dynamic dns registration, or you could have it phone home to some sort of locator service that your app could then query, etc...  But without extra software you are probably out of luck.

Comment: Can u suggest me some of the best way which is free also?

Comment: as @jordan says in another answer, one of the Dynamic IP providers would work, normally their "free" versions come with some limitations (such as having to login to a portal ever x days, or limits on number of changes) so be sure to read their TOS.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a dynamic IP service like www.noip.com. They provide a free linux and/or windows client.

That way, when your public IP changes, you will still be able to connect.